# Enforcing a minimum character length on a form field in I4GL

Tags: informix, 4gl

How can I add character length in a field on Informix 4GL. I have a description column, and I want to enforce a minimum length 10 characters in this field; if the entered string is less than 10 characters, send the user back to re-enter the data.

Answer (score 1):

To enforce that constraint, you would need to use an AFTER FIELD clause, check the length of the entered data, and send the user back if it is not long enough:

```
AFTER FIELD mustbe10
    IF LENGTH(recname.mustbe10) < 10 THEN
        MESSAGE "You must enter at least 10 characters"
        NEXT FIELD mustbe10
    END IF
```

I'm assuming it is a field that does not allow nulls; if it does allow nulls, you need to allow for that in the testing.

---

Incidentally, you can seriously expect to have to deal with descriptions like 'Aaaaaaaaaa' and 'asdfasdfasdf' if you put this requirement on users.  They may also get more creative; you can fit a couple of 4-letter words and an exclamation mark into a 10-character limit.

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Although LENGTH clips trailing blanks without having to use CLIPPED, what happens if a full name containing blanks in between is entered?

Comment: The only blanks discounted by LENGTH() are the trailing ones; leading and interior blanks are counted as part of the length.  AFAICR, an all blank string counts as length 0.